# Angular - add style to class inside shadow-root

Tags: css, angular, sass, styles, shadow-dom

This is what the browser renders:

[image]

The element `super-tabs` is a [library](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-super-tabs). I want to add style to the class `.buttons-container` from the root component
This is what I am trying but it doesn't work:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  :host ::ng-deep super-tabs-toolbar .buttons-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1080px) / 2);
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1080px) / 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: are u trying this in styles.css?

Comment: yes, i am using scss

Answer (score -1):

Add `!important` to overwrite already existing css properties, like so:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  :host ::ng-deep super-tabs-toolbar .buttons-container {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1080px) / 2) !important;
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1080px) / 2) !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem.  I have used selector : host :: ng-deep in other parts of the app and it works, but never to reference within shadow-root, is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: It depends who supports `::ng` , bootstrap do support. best way would be asking directly in there gihub repository.

Comment: does the library need to support ng-deep? Is there another way to override child component styles?

Comment: try without `:host` and `::ng-deep`. it should work

Comment: it doesn't work either. I know very little about styles but I think it is related to what is inside shadow-root?